# I have an idea, I just need someone to point me in the right direction to get started

Tags: android, android-studio, automation

I was wondering if there's a way I can automate the process of fixing patient appointments. The system could be like: patients call the number, the call is automatically received and a welcome message is played and the patients are told to hang up. After which, the patients are sent a text message with the details of their appointments and their phone numbers are recorded.

I'm totally new to this, any ideas where I should get started?

Comment: Welcome! So yoy want to create an automated system for making appointments. Have you considered a simple website for that?

Comment: @robbinc91 I have actually but the problem is, most patients come from rural areas with bad internet (sometimes no internet at all!).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.